# Batch script - unexpected at this time error

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Below is my script where I run "test.bat 1" command in command prompt,
1 is taken as input by my java program and it returns incrementing 1 i.e 2.
This should go on until the value is 10.

Following is my batch script.

```
@echo off

set "java_output="

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:top

for /f "delims=" %%J in ('java -jar test.jar %*') do (
      set "java_output=!java_output! %%J" 
)
set java_output=%java_output%
echo %java_output%

if %java_output% NEQ 10 goto top
endlocal
```

and below is my java code in jar.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        int ret = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        System.out.println(ret+1);
       }
}
```

The following is the output that I am getting.

C:>test.bat 1
 1 2
2 was unexpected at this time.

Can anyone tell me whats the issue.

Comment: Wondering: Why did you add a space to `!java_output!` and `%%J`?, plus you are testing a number, so you must use `set /a "java_output=`

Comment: Thank You. I am new to batch script. Corrected my mistakes. Below is my modified batch script. @echo off

set "java_output="

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:top

for /f "delims=" %%J in ('java -jar test.jar %*') do (
      set /a "java_output=!java_output!%%J" 
)
set java_output=%java_output%
echo %java_output%

if %java_output% NEQ 10 goto top
endlocal  . Now infinite loop is occuring.

Comment: No one can see code in comments... It is so confusing to see in code.

Comment: By the way, you haven't changed all `set "java_output=...." ` to `set /a "java_output=....`

Comment: Just asking: In the last `if` statement, are you sure that is what you want? Are you sure that you need `neq` but not others?

Comment: The code is same I have just removed space between !java_output! and %%J and changed set "java_output" to set /a "java_output" .

Comment: Can you tell us what's `%java_output%` after running the `for` command?

Comment: Yes steve. Because each time the integer gets incremented in my java program. So when it reaches 10 the batch script should stop.

Comment: I run my test.bat by passing argument 1 like this "test.bat 1" . So java_output will be 1,2,3, and so on

Comment: As @Magoo said, your Java program is making the incorrect output, making the batch file confused.

Comment: By the way, I see this when compiling your java code: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at main.main(main.java:5)`

Comment: Actually I created jar from eclipse. So to run java program alone we have provide arguments.

Comment: I see I see. I was compiling your code from an online compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your output in `java_output` is `1 2` (as displayed) then the `if` statement becomes

```
if 1 2 neq 10 ...
```

`if` expects `if string1 op string2 ...` and sees `2` as the comparison operator which must be one of `==`, `equ`, `neq`, `lss`. `leq`, `gtr`, `geq`

Since you are stringing numerics together with spaces, it's extremely unlikely ever to be anything other than not-equal to `10`.

---

Given response:

```
  set "java_output=!java_output! %%J" 
)
set java_output=%java_output%
```

should be

```
  set /a java_output=%%J"
)
```

The

```
set java_output=%java_output%
```

line does nothing and is redundant.

`set /a` assigns a numeric value or arithmetic expression.

Comment: I understood the issue. Is there a way to get only the values that is returned from java program. So that I can get only an integer and not a sequence as you said.

Comment: As you said I have modified the script. Now the integer sequence has gone and Im getting only an integer. But only 2 is getting printed infinitely. Why the value from java program is not getting updated?

Comment: `java -jar test.jar %*` supplies the original parameter list provided to the batch to the `java` routine, If you replace `%*` with `%java_output%` then the value in `java_output` will be supplied. You may need to `set /a java_output=%1` before the `:top` line to assign the value of the first supplied parameter to `java_output` before the first invocation of the `java` routine.

Comment: Thank you Magoo. It works. Thanks for explaining the issue :)